# On Mac, I can't connect install the Python GAMS API despite tutorial. Gives version error

Tags: python, macos, terminal, gams-math

When I run the code on the [GAMS Python API tutorial website](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_PY_TUTORIAL.html#PY_GETTING_STARTED) for initial installation
(current directory is /apifiles/Python, I run `cd api && python setup.py install && cd ..`)

it returns:

```
bash-3.2$ cd api && python setup.py install && cd ..
Fatal Error: Trying to install GAMS Python API 2.7 using Python 3.6
If you want to skip the version check, run the setup.py script specifying '-noCheck'
bash-3.2$ pwd
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get past this small hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

So the key part of that tutorial is the first paragraph:

> The object oriented GAMS Python API is built on top of the different low level component API's and provides convenient access to GAMS from within Python. Examples using the API are located in apifiles/Python while the API itself is found in apifiles/Python/api for Python 2.7, in apifiles/Python/api_26 for Python 2.6 (Windows and Linux only), in apifiles/Python/api_34 for Python 3.4 and in apifiles/Python/api_36 for Python 3.6.

You used `cd api` in your command, which refers to the API folder for Python 2.7.  Based on error message you received, it appears that you trying to run `setup.py` for Python 2.7 API with your Python 3.6 Python interpreter, i.e., your `python` command runs Python 3.6.  So, you just need to change `cd api` to `cd api_36` in your Terminal command and it should work.